# jquery hover function

Tags: jquery, hover

I have the following codes to performs opacity functions, but I want to one of the elements in the class not be included.

for example .bar class.

```
$(".image").hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({opacity: .5}, 'fast')}, function () {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast')

        });
```

can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".image:not(.bar)").hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({opacity: .5}, 'fast')}, function () {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".image").not('.bar').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: .5
    }, 'fast')
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 'fast')

});
```